# How to add custom image dynamically on ToolBar buttons in win32 c++?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to add an icon dynamically on the toolbar, I have HICON of the application but I am not getting how to add that icon to the Toolbar. I have tried many ways but not getting the correct path. So please tell me the way through which I can accomplish my work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not very sure that toolbars support HICONs -- are you using MFC in your application? Please show some code of how you are creating the toolbar and what you have tried to add the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbars win WinApi work internally with Imagelists. You can retrieve the current Imagelist with [TB_GETIMAGELIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and with [Imagelist_AddIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can add y new symbol to it.